# Align tikz picture on the right side of the screen, next to text

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, align

I want to have some code, and then on the right side of it a tikz picture.

I tried 'flushright' but that didn't work.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{a)}
$
\begin{aligned}[t]
&k:4x+3y=0 \text{en A(4,5)} \\
&d(A,k)=\dfrac{|ax_A+by_A-c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \\
&\qquad =\dfrac{|4\cdot 4+3\cdot 5|}{\sqrt{4^2+3^2}} \\
&\qquad =\dfrac{|31|}{5}=\dfrac{31}{5}=6\frac{1}{5}
\end{aligned}
$

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,color=gray!20] (-1,-1) grid (6,5);
\draw(0,0) -- (3,4) -- (5,0) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't leave a blank line between equation and tikz picture. You can specify a baselne for the picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{a)}
$
\begin{aligned}[t]
&k:4x+3y=0 \text{en A(4,5)} \\
&d(A,k)=\dfrac{|ax_A+by_A-c|}{√{a²+b²}} \\
&\qquad =\dfrac{|4    · 4+3    · 5|}{√{4²+3²}} \\
&\qquad =\dfrac{|31|}{5}=\dfrac{31}{5}=6\frac{1}{5}
\end{aligned}
$
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
\draw[step=1cm,color=gray!20] (-1,-1) grid (6,5);
\draw(0,0) -- (3,4) -- (5,0) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust `baseline={(current bounding box.center)}` as you wish, for example, sya `baseline={(current bounding box.north)}`